# Command to Copy/share jmeter master container results (Docker) generated in by running the script in non-gui mode to EC2 instance

Tags: docker, jmeter

We have used two EC2 instances as master and slave with Docker images (Jmeter master container and Jmeter slave container installed in respective hosts). I am able to run my testplan.jmx file from inside the Jmeter master container's bin folder and able to generate results file. How can I copy this results.scv/jtl file to my EC2 instance so that can pull those to my local machine. Please suggest which command i can use. I have used below command but no use.
./jmeter -n -t testplan.jmx -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxxxx -Dclient.rmi.localport=yyy0 -Rxxxxx -l /home/ubuntu/results2.jtl

Here /home/ubuntu/Jmeter is the folder which i have in my local EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to accomplish the task by using below command. This command needs to be run from host machine/EC2 instance (not from the jmeter master container)

docker cp :

in my case: docker cp 8xxxxxxx:/jmeter/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/results.jtl /home/ubuntu/xxx/JMdriver/

ContainerID can get using docker ps -a

Thanks.